# Ridge regression, argmax of the MAP

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, prior

[image]

How can i prove it? I only proved that it is equivalent to $$arg\min_w \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-w_0-\textbf{w}^T\textbf{x}_i)^2+\lambda||\textbf{w}||^2_2$$

Comment: $1/N$ is just a constant, doesn't matter.

Comment: @marti_0603 Welcome! Please can you edit the question to type the equations in LaTeX/MathJax? It will help those who relies on screen readers to understand the equations.

Comment: But 1/N multiplies only the sum, not also the other term, doesn't matter anyway?